# AngularJs Datatables implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am new to AngularJs and i want to implement a data-table like we do in JQuery for that i came across [Louis Lin Angular-datatable](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) i have copied the html and JS as is from the site , but still i am unable to use it properly for example

### For 'with-options' section their implementation shows like

[image: Theirs]

### Mine looks like

[image: Mine]

Am i missing something , please let me know if there is any complete example of using this datatable.

 Also i see error message in console like 

**TypeError: this.renderDataTableAndEmitEvent** is not a function, is there some problem with this library.

Comment: We need to see your code - no one can tell what exactly you have missed without that :) There is no particular problems with angular datatables. When you meet a new project (hosted on github) is a good idea always to check out the [issues](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues) section - it quickly becomes clear if the project is seriously maintained and uptodate.

Comment: @davidkonrad : yes correct,Thanks for your input. Actually the error was in imports ordering for the JS files.I am attaching the file with the corrected code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was with the ordering of the imported JS files due to which i was getting

```
Datatables.renderer module is missing.
```

I have found a workaround and nice working solution from this [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/YIwHiU16odhmNxdWL6JF/preview)